# How to import a vcf file into LibreOffice Calc

Tags: libreoffice

Is there an easy way to import a vcf-file with all contacts from my adroid into a table in LibreOffice calc?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use Thunderbirds addressbook as workaround:

- **Tools->import** the VCF-File into Thunderbirds adressbook

it will show up as a new addressbook in the list. Due to a bug, you have to select another addressbook and then the new imported addressbook again to see the content.

If you are happy, then select that adressbook and select

- **Tools->export** into a CSV file
- open the CSV-File with LibreOffice Calc